# Numerical solution to a Legendre differential equation - approximating using tridiagonal matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

My task is to solve this differential equation:
$$(1−x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}−2x\frac{dy}{dx}+p(p+1)2y=0,y(0) = y₀, y(a)=yǎ$$
I need to solve it numerically using linear equations with a tridiagonal matrix. I am struggling with the first step - creating this tridiagonal matrix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't yet but I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understand correctly what it is you want to do, but I presume you need to use some sort of finite difference scheme.

Numerically you want to discretize an interval into let's say N points with spacing $\Delta x$. Your variable $x$ will now be a "vector" with N entries like $[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N]^T$.
You'll still have to deal with the derivatives now.
If you look at the finite difference scheme:
$$y_i''=  \frac{y_{i+1}-2y_i+y_{i-1}}{\Delta x}$$
The second derivative therefore is really represented as "matrix" - it really should be that way since the derivative is a linear operator!

This is a tridiagonal matrix and with a bit of notational abuse:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{(\Delta x)^2}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 1 &  &  0\\
    1 & -2 & \ddots &  \\
     & \ddots & \ddots & 1\\
    0 &  & 1 & -2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
You'll also need to do this for the first derivative. Then rewrite this as an eigenvalue equation:
$$\hat{L} y = \lambda y,$$
where the operator $$\hat{L} = (1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d^2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2} - 2x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ is represented as a tridiagonal matrix and you'll need to solve for eigenfunctions.
Hints:

- Watch out for the boundary conditions!
- Be careful when dealing with $x$, represent it as a diagonal matrix (It'd be better to use index notation in order to avoid confusion).

I hope this helps!